# Why points above 85N or below -85S are not shown on the iPhone map?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mapkit, coordinates, mkannotation

I need to represent on the map (iPhone) some points such as (88, 60) or (90, 55), but the custom annotations representing these points get deallocated. I also noticed that these points are not actually displayed on the google map, they are somehow above the visible map. This happens for any point that is above 85 deg. N latitude or -85 deg. S latitude.

Comment: I'd imagine the map projection can't easily handle polar points.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old post, but just to answer your question.
Most (allmost all) commercial maps are displayed in the mercator projection. This is what you see in mapKit or on google maps. This means that the latitude and longitude lines run horizontal and vertical.
If you would change this to for instance polar project (world from the top) it would become way to difficult to calculate the postion of objects because the lat and long lines converge rapidly...

So it's just for ease of use....

Comment: No, it's not hard to calculate how to place markers on a polar projection. The reason the maps cut off at 85 degrees is because the poles on a Mercator projection are infinitely far apart. You would have to make the middle of the map (where most people live) smaller and smaller for every line of latitude you wanted to add.